# RegEx Python Find and Print to a new document

Tags: python, regex, export

Sorry if this is a dumb lump of questions, but I had a couple things I was hoping to inquire about. Basically, what I am trying to do is take a file that is being sent where a bunch of data is getting clumped all together that is supposed to be on separate lines, sort through it, and print each statement on its own line. The thing I don't know is how to create a new document for everything to be dumped into, nor do I know how to print into that document where each thing is on its new line.

I've decided to try and tackle this task while using Regular Expressions and Python. I want my code to look for any of four specific strings (MTH|, SCN|, ENG|, or HST|) and copy everything after it UNTIL it runs into one of those four strings again. At that point I need it to stop, record everything it copied, and then start copying the new string. I need to make it read past new lines and ignore them, which I hope to accomplish with

```
re.DOTALL
```

Basically, I want my code to take something like this:

```
MTH|stuffstuffstuffSCN|stuffstuffstuffENG|stuffstuffstuffHST|stuffstu
ffstuffSCN|stuffstuffstuffENG|stuffstuffstuffHST|stuffstuffstuffMTH|s
tuffstuffstuffSCN|stuffstuffstuffENG|stuffstuffstuff
```

And turn into something nice and readable like this:

```
MTH|stuffstuffstuff

SCN|stuffstuffstuff 

ENG|stuffstuffstuff

HST|stuffstuffstuff

SCN|stuffstuffstuff

ENG|stuffstuffstuff

HST|stuffstuffstuff

MTH|stuffstuffstuff

SCN|stuffstuffstuff

ENG|stuffstuffstuff
```

While also creating a new document and pasting it all in that .txt file. My code looks like this so far:

```
import re
re.DOTALL
from __future__ import print_function
NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of to-be-made document")
log = open("C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Python\NDoc.txt", "w")
#Need help with this^ How do I make new file instead of opening a file?

nl = list()
file = raw_input("Enter a file to be sorted")
xfile = open(file)

for line in xfile:
        l=line.strip()
        n=re.findall('^([MTH|SCN|ENG|HST][|].)$[MTH|SCN|ENG|HST][|]',l)
                           #Edited out some x's here that I left in, sorry
            if len(n) > 0:
                nl.append(n)
for item in nl:
    print(item, file = log)
```

In the starting file, stuffstuffstuff can be number, letters, and various symbols (including | ), but no where except where they are supposed to be will MTH| SCN| ENG| HST| occur, so I want to look specifically for those 4 strings as my starts and ends.

Aside from being able to create a new document and paste into it on separate lines for each item in list, will the above code accomplish what I am trying to do? Can I scan .txt files and excel files? I don't have a file to test it on till Friday but I am supposed to have it mostly done by then.

Oh, also, to do things like:

```
import.re
re.DOTALL
from __future__ import print_function
```

do I have to set anything external? Are these addons or things I need to import or are these all just built into python?

Comment: Would replacing each instance of ("MTH|", "SCN|", "ENG|", "HST|") with ("\n\nMTH|", "\n\nSCN|", "\n\nENG|", "\n\nHST|") work for you? I think that is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will take your string and put newlines in between each string you wanted to separate:

```
re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|SCN|ENG|HST)[|]))","\n\n",line)
```

Here is the code I was testing with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
#NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of to-be-made document")
#log = open("C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Python\NDoc.txt", "w")
#Need help with this^ How do I make new file instead of opening a file?

#nl = list()
#file = raw_input("Enter a file to be sorted")
xfile = open("file2")

for line in xfile:
    l=line.strip()
    n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|SCN|ENG|HST)[|]))","\n\n",line)
                       #Edited out some x's here that I left in, sorry
    if len(n) > 0:
      nl=n.split("\n")
      for item in nl:
         print(item)
```

I've tested this version with input data that has no newlines. I also have a version that works with newlines. If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll post that version.

The main environmental changes I made are that I'm reading from a file named "file2" in the same directory as the python script and I'm just writing the output to the screen.

This version assumes that there are newlines in your data and just reads the whole file in:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
#NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of to-be-made document")   
#log = open("C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\Python\NDoc.txt", "w")
#Need help with this^ How do I make new file instead of opening a file?

#nl = list()
#file = raw_input("Enter a file to be sorted")
xfile = open("file")

line = xfile.read()
l=line.strip()
l=re.sub("\n","",l)
n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|SCN|ENG|HST)[|]))","\n\n",l)
print(n)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! So are you saying that I should use that code instead of something (such as my findall() and list functions) or am I supposed to plug that in after something?

Comment: First: I need to know if there are newlines in your sample data?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm pretty sure the data I am getting is going to be a .txt with a continuous line of characters and that there are no breaks in it.

Comment: OK, I've updated my post with sample code. If it doesn't work, let me know and we'll try the other version. The other version just reads the entire file as a big string, removes any existing newlines and then splits on the character strings you referenced above.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks, I will try this out as soon as I am given a piece of sample data. Just out of curiosity, how would the other code look by comparison?

Also, you have a lot of old stuff commented out. Was this because it was not needed or you just didn't want it acting while you were testing?

Comment: I'll post the other sample code as well. Most of what I commented out wasn't needed using the gsub method. Since we're splitting the string, we don't need to put it into an array to print each element out. The split creates it's own array. What you would need is to go back and open the file you want to write to - like your log file.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So just to double check, where it says

    n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|SCN|ENG|HST)[|]))","\n\n",l)

the /n/n at the end is making it double-spaced, right? If I wanted it to not have spaces between found strings, would I just put /n?

Also, this printing is just coming out in the terminal, right? Is there a way to create a new document and print to it inside of the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84094/discussion-between-gymbrall-and-scott-t).